# joining tables vs key dictionary

Tags: sql, performance, entity-framework, linq, query-performance

I have some questions about efficiency on making a query on entity framework.
Suppose i have Table A that is joined to 10 different Table B,C,D.....
and I wanted to get the values of B.Name,C.Name,C.value,D.......(etc etc)
is it better to just use Linq to join all the tables and do all so in one query?
such as

```
var datas = from a in dataTable.A
join b in dataTable.B on a.bID = b.ID
...
select new {a.ID,a.valueOfsomething, b.Name.....}
```

or would it be more efficient to have a bunch of dictionary such as

```
Dictionary<int,TableB> bDictionary = dataTable.B.ToDictionary(x=>ID)
...
result.bValue = bDictionary[datas.bID.Value].Name
```

Lets suppose we're dealing on Table A with about 100,000 rows and each table has about 5-10 columns and the list I'm getting after the query might get those 100,000 rows in a single go

Comment: join is 225 times faster than dictionary or where clause... so i prefer join instead of using dictionary.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------
Search Strategy       |  Found |      Time
---------------------------------------------------
Join                          | 210366 |    157 ms.
Dictionary Contain   | 210366 |    325 ms.
HashSet Contain     | 210366 |    325 ms.
---------------------------------------------------

Comment: i see thank you very much its just that joining 10 tables at once isnt a pretty sight and i was searching for some method of joining tables and i found dictionary but anyway thank you very much :D

Comment: can i put that in an answer ? if it worked for u ?

Comment: I don't see where this has anything to do with SQL or Entity Framework, assuming your data table variables are of type `DataTable`.

Comment: `join` actually uses a `Lookup` internally, which is a special purpose `Dictionary` that provides for multiple values per key. You can use `ToLookup` directly as well, but if you need values from all ten tables, you might as well use `join`.